# The requested URL was not found on this server when using PHP Mamp, Xamp

Tags: php, xampp, mamp

I using Mamp  to create Php server.
Default Home page is homecontroller. but when i click on url lead to Home or any url, it got a problem: The requested URL /ltw/home was not found on this server. when i replace         protected $controller = "home";  by any controller, it can load when i go to index page.

```
 class App
{
    protected $controller = "home";
    protected $action = "default";
    protected $params = [];
    
   public function __construct()
    {
        //Array ( [0] => home [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 )
        $arr = $this->UrlProcess();
       // print_r($arr);

        //Handle Controller
        if (file_exists("./mvc/controllers/". $arr[0] ."Controller.php")){
            $this->controller = $arr[0];
            unset($arr[0]);
        } 
        require_once "./mvc/controllers/" . $this->controller . "Controller.php";
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        //Handle Action
        if (isset($arr[1]) && method_exists($this->controller, $arr[1])){
            $this->action = $arr[1];
            unset($arr[1]);
        }

        //Handle Params
        $this->params = $arr?array_values($arr):[];
        $arr2 = array($this->params);
        
        //Call a controller->action->params
        call_user_func_array([ $this->controller, $this->action ], $arr2 );
        // print_r($this->params);
    }
```

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBzaC.png)

This error occur only on mac and xampp,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use in your .htacess root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mvc/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If it doesn't help, you should modify your main controller to:

```
<?php

class Core
{
    public function start() {
   
    $url = '/';
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url .= $_GET['url'];
    }

   
    $params = array();

    if (!empty($url) && $url != '/') {
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        
        array_shift($url);

        $currentController = $url[0].'Controller';
        
        array_shift($url); 

        if (isset($url[0]) && !empty($url[0])) {
            $currentAction = $url[0];
            array_shift($url);
        } else {
            $currentAction = 'index';
        }

        if (count($url) > 0) {
             $params = $url;
        }
 
    } else {
        $currentController = 'homeController';
        $currentAction = 'index';
    }

    
    if ( !(file_exists('controllers/'.$currentController.'.php') || file_exists('controllersReport/'.$currentController.'.php')) || !method_exists($currentController, $currentAction)) {
        $currentController = 'notfoundController';
        $currentAction = 'index';
    } 

    $c = new $currentController();
    call_user_func_array(array($c, $currentAction), $params);
    }
}
```